# Checkbox value not updating correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, html-helper

I am calling a controller's action method which returns a bool value. Based on this bool output, I am checking/unchecking a checkbox in the UI. This works fine until I view a record where the checkbox value is unchecked. After this all the records shows the checkbox as unchecked even though the output is true and the control is rendered correctly with checked attribute set as "checked".

```
  $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("IsUserActive", "Account")',
                      cache: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      data: { userName: data.UserName },
                      success: function (output) {
                          if(output == "True")
                              $("#isActive").attr("checked", true);
                          else
                              $("#isActive").attr("checked", false);
                          $("#pwdResetModal").modal('show');
                      }
                  });

 @using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserName, new { id = "userName" })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsActive)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive,new { id = "isActive" })
        </li>
    </ol>

</fieldset>
<button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced .attr with .prop and everything seems to be working fine now.

```
$("#isActive").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  You should mark this as the answer.